# width and height behavior different in web and ios

Tags: react-native, expo

I am new in the react native ecosystem. I am developing a react native app with expo and I see some things weirds.
My simple code is:

```
export function Practical({ navigation }: any): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.primro}>
        <View style={styles.ultimo}>
          <Text>Hola</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
const yellow = 'yellow';
const purple = 'purple';
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  primro: {
    backgroundColor: yellow,
    height: '141px',
    width: '341px',
  },
  ultimo: {
    backgroundColor: purple,
    height: '100px',
    width: '200px',
  },
});
```

I am seeing this in web:
[image]

I see this in ios:
[image]

And this is what I see in chrome with the iphone view, and I would expect to see in the xcode simulator:
[image]

Thanks!!

I tried with several structures.

Comment: You may try using number for height and width for the views. E.g. change `height: '141px'` to `height: 141`.

Comment: Hi!
If I do that I lose width and height for web and remains the same in ios.
Thanks for your answer!